# EaglView is not responding in iOS 9.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Method of `ES1Renderer.m`

```
context_ = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];
```

This line code is not executing in iOS 9.3.2, else in all iOS version working fine.

Comment: what is your question.....

Comment: do you get some error? can you share it?

Comment: when trying to cun the code on ipad air 9.3.2, for the first time it get the _context and return the view but for the 2nd time if we run the same code without killing app from ipad then it get stuck at  "context_ = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];"